# Optional parameter of function is making "null" an option of dropdown list. How to remove it?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I've built a custom connector and I decided to change the parameter of a function in the Navigator to a dropdown list.
For that, I had to provide function documentation, and since the parameter for the function has to be optional (I don't want it to be passed to Top Level Navigation function), it generated a "null" option:

[image]

It doesn't cause any errors because it is handled, but I'd like it to disappear. How do I do that without removing "optional" from my parameter? I understand that if nothing is selected, it should be "null" but I don't want it as an option in the list.

Here is some sample code for clarity:

```
Params = type text
meta [
Documentation.FieldCaption = "Time Range (Default is medium):",
Documentation.AllowedValues = {"Short (4 weeks)","Medium (6 months)","Long (Overall)"}];

Function1Type = type function(
optional time_range as Params)
as table;

[DataSource.Kind="Project1"]
shared Project1.Function1 = (optional Params) => Value.ReplaceType(Function1, Function1Type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't remove the blank/null value, if it is an optional parameter.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Optional-parameter-of-function-is-making-quot-null-quot-as-a/m-p/883202#M30040